# The range of r can be r<1 and r>1

Tags: z-transform, poles-zeros

[image]

I have to find the range of r which makes H(z) stable.  There is no restriction of left sided or right sided.
Then, both r<1 (z>r) and r > 1  can be the answer?

Comment: Hi and welcome. Please use latex and other sketching tools to make the question clearer. You can take references from other questions.

Comment: there are typically 2 and sometimes 3 regions of convergence also abbreviated as ROC.which are you asking about?

Comment: I have to find the range of r to make H(z) stable, and find h(n). But there are no restriction about left-sided or right-sided, or causality. Then, the 4th term of h(n) can be two case for r<1, and r>1?

Comment: stability is related to the appropriate ROC

Comment: Yes I know that, but there is no clue that determine ROC as 4th term, then should i classify the case for the answer?